# Clojure: implementing stateful Java interface

Tags: java, clojure, interface, apache-kafka, reify

[Kafka Streams](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.1/streams/index.html) has an interface, [`Processor`](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/Processor.html), the implementation of which is stateful. An [example implementation](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.1/streams/developer-guide.html#defining-a-stream-processor) given in the developer guide is:

```java
public class WordCountProcessor implements Processor<String, String> {

  private ProcessorContext context;
  private KeyValueStore<String, Long> kvStore;

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
      // keep the processor context locally because we need it in punctuate() and commit()
      this.context = context;

      // call this processor's punctuate() method every 1000 time units.
      this.context.schedule(1000);

      // retrieve the key-value store named "Counts"
      kvStore = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore("Counts");
  }

  @Override
  public void process(String dummy, String line) {
      String[] words = line.toLowerCase().split(" ");

      for (String word : words) {
          Long oldValue = kvStore.get(word);
          if (oldValue == null) {
              kvStore.put(word, 1L);
          } else {
              kvStore.put(word, oldValue + 1L);
          }
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void punctuate(long timestamp) {
      KeyValueIterator<String, Long> iter = this.kvStore.all();
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
          KeyValue<String, Long> entry = iter.next();
          context.forward(entry.key, entry.value.toString());
      }
      iter.close();
      // commit the current processing progress
      context.commit();
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
      // close the key-value store
      kvStore.close();
  }

}
```

The `init` method initializes `WordCountProcessor`'s internal state, such as retrieving a key-value store. Other methods, like `process` and `close`, make use of this state.

It's not clear to me how to `reify` such an interface in Clojure. How would we pass on the state retrieved by `init` to `process`, `close`, etc.?

### Using a closure?

One idea I have is to use a closure:

```clj
(let [ctx (atom nil)]
  (reify Processor
    (close [this]
      ;; Do something w/ ctx
      )
    (init [this context]
      (reset! ctx context))
    (process [this k v]
      ;; Do something w/ ctx
      )
    (punctuate [this timestamp]
      ;; Do something w/ ctx
      )))
```

Annoyingly, we'd have to start with the `ProcessorContext` object each time, so the key-value store code would be repeated across all methods that need the key-value store.

I don't see a (general) way around that, though on a case-by-case basis we can replace the `ctx` atom with more specific state that the methods need.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing over an atom would be the main way to do it. Your original class has two fields, so you can close over two atoms to get the same effect

```
(let [ctx (atom nil)
      kv-store (atom nil)]
  (reify Processor
    ,,,
    (init [this context]
      (reset! ctx context)
      (reset! kv-store (.getStateStore context "Counts")))
    ,,,))
```

If that's still too tedious then you can add some convenience functions that also close over the atoms

```
(let [ctx (atom nil)
      kv-store (atom nil)]

  (def kv-get [key]
    (.get @kv-store key))

  (def kv-all []
    (iterator-seq (.all @kv-store)))

  (def kv-put [key value]
    (.put @kv-store key value))

  (reify Processor
    ,,,
    (init [this context]
      (reset! ctx context)
      (reset! kv-store (.getStateStore context "Counts")))
    ,,,
  (punctuate [this timestamp]
    (do-seq [x (kv-all)]
      ,,,)
  )))
```

The alternative would be to use [gen-class](https://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html), but  think you'll be better off with reify.